# how to get product selectable option via API?

Tags: product, api, custom-options, web-services

is it  possible to get product selectable option (like : size , color , ...) via API in magento store ?

Comment: You mean to get a list of all option values available for the product?

Comment: @Tim yes get list of options and select them to get price of product\

Comment: Did you find a way to do that in SOAP API V2?

Answer (score 1):

The current Magento APIs don't provide methods to deal with configurable product and thus that kind of use cases are not provided by the APIs. You can create your own module that extends the SOAP API and adds a new operation that retrieves the information you want (e.g. product attributes). To do that, take a look at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

and

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/

My company is working on a solution for that kind of problems and limitations with the current Magento APIs. We expect to release it as soon as we can.

Comment: very good news , the module will be free or you have pricing plan for that ?

Comment: The API will be a paid hosted service, but we can’t talk about exact prices yet. What I can anticipate is that it will have a generous free tier. We have a product website where you can sign up to our mailing list, so you can receive an email as soon as it’s available (http://meets.io) or you can follow us on twitter: @meetsio

Comment: Did you had any chance of making such API? I am interested in purchase for Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: Sorry for the late response @FahimParkar . Take a look at this Magento extension: https://marketplace.magento.com/theam-bridge-api.html